# How to use withDefault wrappers?

Tags: kotlin

I want to use `MutableMap` [with defaults](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-default.html):

```
val myMap = mutableMapOf<String, Set<String>>().withDefault { mutableSetOf() }
```

but I can't use `getOrImplicitDefault` method because `withDefault` returns `MutableMap<String, Set<String>>` type. Moreover, I can't cast to `MutableMapWithDefault` interface because [this is a private interface](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kt#L60).

I can't use `get` method either because it returns a nullable type. It is ok because this is a method on the `MutableMap` interface (moreover it doesn't call `defaultValue` callback for take default value).

Seems like this functionality is not correctly implemented in Kotlin,  or I am using it wrong. So, how do I use `withDefault` wrappers correctly?

Comment: Guava's [`SetMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) or [`LoadingCache`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) look like a better fit for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.0 a wrapper returned by `withDefault` is only usable in property delegation use cases.

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Set<String>>().withDefault { mutableSetOf() }

var property: Set<String> by map // returns empty set by default
```

Answer (score 8):

Looks like in Kotlin 1.1 this actually works if you use the [getValue()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html) function instead of the `get()` function.

Comment: Looks like the default value is returned, but not put into the map... rather useless.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it to be put into the map if just calling getValue() again gets you the value again?

Comment: I want to provide a default way to create an object with the provided key if the map doesn't contain any value with this key. This is how the withDefault works in Groovy and I want to do the same thing in Kotlin. Because I need to retrieve the same instance after the init and I need to mutate it.
Here is the Groovy way to do this thing: http://mrhaki.blogspot.ch/2010/07/groovy-goodness-map-with-default-values.html

Comment: Design discussion on this method: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11851

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for a way to return default value from a MutableMap, but also store it at the same time for future retrieval. The `.withDefault` only returns the default value, but doesn't store it. Calling `.getOrPut` every time I need to retrieve a value doesn't look like a good idea. I've came up with something like this:

```kotlin
val myMap = with(mutableMapOf<String, Set<String>>()) {
    withDefault { key -> getOrPut(key, { mutableSetOf<String>() }) }
}
```

This calls [`getOrPut`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html) within [`withDefault` wrapper](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-default.html) on the backing [MutableMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/) object, which puts the missing key-value pair into the map and returns it.

To encapsulate the behaviour you can create a [delegated property provider](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#providing-a-delegate).

```kotlin
/** Wraps a [MutableMap]. Will generate a [defaultValue] if none exists, and set it into the map. */
fun <K, V> mapWithPutDefault(defaultValue: (key: K) -> V): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, MutableMap<K, V>> =
  object : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, MutableMap<K, V>> {

    private var map: MutableMap<K, V> = with(mutableMapOf<K, V>()) {
      withDefault { key -> getOrPut(key) { defaultValue(key) } }
    }

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): MutableMap<K, V> = map

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: MutableMap<K, V>) {
      this.map = value
    }
  }

fun main() {
    val myMap: MutableMap<String, String> by mapWithPutDefault { "some default value for $it" }
    println("map is empty: $myMap")
    // map is empty: {}
    val someValue = myMap.getValue("my-key")
    println("map returns a default value: $someValue")
    // map returns a default value: some default value for my-key
    println("map now has a value: $myMap")
    // map now has a value: {my-key=some default value for my-key}
}
```

Comment: Very nice! To make it more slick, and to help with code duplication, you can use a delegated property to encapsulate the behaviour: https://pl.kotl.in/mqewmh-uR. (I've submitted an edit in case that link doesn't work.)

Answer (score 3):

Map `withDefault` returns a wrapper of the read-only map, having the implicit default value provided with the specified function defaultValue. This implicit default value is used when the original map doesn't contain a value for the key specified. See the usage of `getOrElse` & `getOrDefault` as well that works the same way as for lists -

```
val emojiMap = mapOf("Grinning Face" to "", "Winking face" to "", 
                "Zany face" to "").withDefault({""})

fun main()
{
    println(emojiMap) // {Grinning Face=, Winking face=, Zany face=}
    println(emojiMap.getValue("Grinning Face")) // 
    println(emojiMap.getValue("Zany face")) // 
    println(emojiMap.getValue("Smiling face")) // 

    // getOrElse & getOrDefault
    println(emojiMap.getOrElse("Flushed face"){""}) // 
    println(emojiMap.getOrDefault("Sad face","")) // 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following method:

```
myMap.getOrPut(someKey,{DEFAULT_VALUE})
```

Documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, all the implementations of `getOrImplicitDefault` redirect t to `getOrElseNullable`. Maybe try that.

Comment: This solution has a problem: need to specify lambda with default value for every call of `getOrElseNullable` method. I try to avoid this and want to declare default value in one place only.